# Should I be using eval() here?

Tags: matlab, eval

I have read up on the proper use of eval() and to be honest, I can't tell whether my usage falls into the "it's good" or "it's terrible" category. Please advise!

Here is what my code does:

> f='exp(-x)' %character string of function that I want to use
>
> G=GetGradient(f) %symbolically gets the gradient of function f under a certain mapping
>
> x=whatever %vector x is assigned through other means
>
> answer=eval(G) %The output is the gradient G evaluated at points x.

The important thing for me is 'answer', the Gradient function at all the points in vector x (determined in some other way). Is eval right here? Thanks.

Comment: are you doing symbolic math or numerical? can your function `GetGradient` take in a vector and spit out an output?

Comment: the GetGradient function takes a char string and spits out its gradient (after a mapping x-->z(x) ), using symbolic math

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest the following alternative, assuming that `G` is, in your example, the string `'-exp(-x)'`. [STR2FUNC](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/str2func.html) converts your function string into an anonymous function, which you can then evaluate as usual.

```
gradFun = str2func(['@(x)' G]); %# this assumes that x is the independent variable in G

x = whatever;

answer = gradFun(x); %# or answer = gradFun(whatever);
```

EDIT: If `GetGradient` returns a symbolic expression, you can convert it to string using `char`.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. G is the gradient of f='exp(-x)' after a certain transformation x-->z(x). The GetGradient function takes the gradient of the function f after the mapping x --> z(x)

Comment: @Nadav: It seems the other Jonas' solution should still do what you want, it doesn't really matter what exact string GetGradient outputs as long as it is an expression which can be evaluated by Matlab (as you suggest by your use of eval()) and which does not depend on any other variables. Note that using str2func seems to make particular sense if you want to call that function many times (since parsing will only happen once as opposed to many calls to eval). If you only need to call the function for one value of x with a given string G, I'd say you can stick with eval.

Comment: @Nadav: If you use `char` on a symbolic expression, it should create a string for you.